# How to configure VM host-only adapter to be able to access internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I'm running Windows 10 with Virtualbox and Linux in it. I would like to configure both system to be able to access internet from guest OS using Host-only adapter. I know there is an easier way to use NAT, but I would like to hide my VM on network, so I would like to use windows shared internet connection to access internet from guest. So far I have created a new Virtual host-only adapter, and I set windows to share my WiFi connection with it. Windows automatically set IP address of my host-only adapter to 192.168.137.1. (DHCP server disabled). I configure virtual machine to use this adapter, and then tried to configure guest linux network as following: IP address: 192.168.137.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.137.1

But I am not able to access internet from guest.

Is there a way how to do it? What's wrong with my setup?

Thanks.